# How I can view my uploaded pdf from firebase storage with flutter?

Tags: firebase, flutter, pdf, dart, firebase-storage

I have recently uploaded a pdf file to firebase storage via picking a pdf by [file_picker](https://pub.dev/packages/file_picker) plugin.
now file is uploaded successfully :

[image]

but when I go to firebase storage : tapped on that pdf link , showing ERROR MESSAGE `failed to load pdf decoument`

[image]

Code for picking pdf via file_picker

```
void sendPdf() async {
   FilePickerResult result = await FilePicker.platform.pickFiles(
    
     type: FileType.custom,
   allowedExtensions: ['pdf'],
   );

   if(result != null) {
     File file = File(result.files.single.path);
       _storageMethods.uploadPdf(
       pdf: file, 
       uploaderId: widget.adminUser.uid,
       courseTitle:_courseTitleController.text,
       coursePrice:_coursePriceController.text,
      uploadProvider: _uploadProvider);
   } else {
     // User canceled the picker
   }
    
   
 }
```

Code for uploading a file to firebase storage:

```
Future<String> uploadPdfToStorage(File pdfFile) async {
   try {
     Reference ref = FirebaseStorage.instance.ref().child('pdfs/${DateTime.now().millisecondsSinceEpoch}');
   UploadTask uploadTask = ref.putFile(pdfFile, SettableMetadata(contentType: 'pdf')); 

    TaskSnapshot snapshot = await uploadTask;

   String url = await snapshot.ref.getDownloadURL();


 print("url:$url");
 return  url;
   } catch (e) {
     return null;
   }
 }
```

Comment: There's not a lot for us to go on here, so I recommend taking some more troubleshooting steps yourself. For example: if you download the file from the Firebase console, can you open the result as a PDF locally? If not, the upload likely went wrong.

Comment: I suggest checking to see if there is a problem with the PDF itself.  The code here might not be a problem at all.

Comment: There is nothing wrong with pdf file, Now I found the issue, actually I was passing wrong `contentType` in storage . it should not be only `pdf`. it must be `contentType: 'application/pdf'`.

Answer (score 1):

Have found the issue with `contentType`

```
 UploadTask uploadTask = ref.putFile(pdfFile, SettableMetadata(contentType: 'pdf'));
```

I've replaced with:

```
 UploadTask uploadTask = ref.putFile(pdfFile, SettableMetadata(contentType: 'application/pdf'));
```